# WebDriver + Protractor with grunt

Tags: webdriver, gruntjs, protractor

I'm trying to run end-to-end tests with WebDriver and Protractor. No problem when I run it manually with:
    webdriver-manager start
and then
    protractor test-UI/e2e/conf.js

Now I would like to launch them from a grunt command, so I tried with grunt-shell, joining them with '&&'. But as WebDriver waits, tests are never started. Did someone try this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fork of Grunt-shell called Grunt-shell-spawn ([Github Repo](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn)) which allows you to run background processes asynchronously. This happens to work very well with starting the selenium webdriver server helping to automate the protractor testing process. There are a few grunt plugins specifically for starting the webdriver server but from my experience they all have small bugs that cause errors once the tests are finished or require you to mark a flag `keepAlive: true` which means it will not kill the webdriver server process forcing you to ctrl+c or close and re-open the command prompt which can cause a lot of issues when devs are using the functional tests and with continuous integration (CI) servers. Grunt-shell-spawn has the ability to kill the process as you can see at the end of my 'test' task which is really invaluable for maintaining consistency and ease of use.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');

var path = require('path'); 

grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  ...
  ...
  shell: {
    updateserver: {
      options: {
        stdout: true
      },
      command: "node " + path.resolve('node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager') + ' update --standalone --chrome'
    },
     startserver: {
      options: {
        stdout:false,
        stdin: false,
        stderr: false,
        async:true
      },
      command:  'node ' + path.resolve('node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager') + ' start --standalone'
    },
});

grunt.registerTask('test',[
    'shell:updateserver',
    'shell:startserver',
    'protractor:e2e',
    'shell:startserver:kill'
]);
```

Comment: you're a life-saver!

Answer (score 4):

You can to install `grunt-protractor-runner`

```
npm install grunt-protractor-runner --save-dev
```

Check this blog with details

http://www.codeorbits.com/blog/2014/01/26/angularjs-end-to-end-testing-with-protractor-easy-set-up-with-yeoman/

Answer (score 0):

Try running `grunt --verbose` to see more details on whats happening.